# svg: How to set a circle on the calculated line?

Tags: svg, d3.js, line, geometry

I'm trying to set a circle on the calculated line with svg.

Here is my the example: http://jsfiddle.net/7XC9j/

html:

```
<svg width="300" height="500">
  <g id="g-1"></g>
</svg>
```

javascript:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
  .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
  .interpolate("cardinal")
  .tension(0);

 var points = [{x: 0, y: 200}, {x: 25, y: 180}, {x: 50, y: 150}, {x: 100, y: 145}, {x: 200, y: 130}, {x: 300, y: 120}, {x: 500, y: 25}];

 d3.select("#g-1").append("path").attr("d", line(points));
```

and now I try to set the circle (depends of X to the line), however I look for some function like `line(myX).x` for drawing the circle:

```
 d3.select("#g-1").append("svg:circle")
    .attr("cx", myX)
    .attr("cy", line(myX).x)
    .attr("r", 4.5);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `path.getPointAtLength(i)`

see
   http://jsfiddle.net/GQ8WJ/

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method for adding a circle that uses the 4th object in the `points` array.

Working fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/3RumJ/

**JavaScript**

```
d3.select("#g-1")
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", points[3].x )
    .attr("cy", points[3].y )
    .attr("r", 4.5);
```

Comment: :) Yes, with precise points that is simple, but I want to show the circle also between the points, e.g. x=15

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be solution: http://jsfiddle.net/amgq3/
In this example I take `x` from 0 to 500 and use function `line` to get required `y`

Comment: not bed, but I need to use `interpolate("cardinal")` by drawing the line.

Comment: I've tried to do it, but without success. Sorry. I just came up with get random coords of cicrle before plotting of line, then add it to array `points` and then plot line - but I think it's not what you want =)