# Drawing weighted circles on an svg path

Tags: d3.js

I have a set of nodes with weight and a title.
How can I render these data as circles with following conditions using D3 js:

1. circles should place on a predefined path (for example a tree in SVG format)
2. circles should not interfere with each other
3. each circle should have radius in relation with its weight
4. having a reference predefined central point in the predefined path(condition 1), the distance of each circle to this reference point is also determined by its weight.the most weighted node should be the nearest to the reference point.
5. circles should be limited in a frame (width and height)

Is it necessary to use D3 or it can be simply done using an algorithm on html5 canvas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can do this in plain Javascript. Would you mind sharing the code you have so far?

Comment: still no code.thought it would be easy with D3.But still didn't find any similar sample.

Comment: For putting circles on a path, see e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187417/svg-how-to-set-a-circle-on-the-calculated-line). For adjusting the size of circles according to data, see e.g. [this tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/circle.html).

Comment: Thanks lars.and what about drawing without interference?

Comment: I think we can examine it by testing : r1 + r2 < distanceOfCenters and replacing circle if that was false.Is that right?

Comment: Yes, in general you can use D3's [quadtree](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3231298).

Comment: Thanks a lot lars.I will prepare a sample and inform you to correct me.